# fixed centered bottom background position

Tags: css

I am thinking I can do this with jQuery, but am attempting with CSS only, I am trying to position a background image that is fixed to the center and bottom of the page. My div is 1024 wide while the height depends on the content. I want the background image to stay centered until the browser is sized below 1024 wide, at which point I want the background image to be set to the left.(keeping the correct background size.

this is what I have in code thus far.

```
.scroll-stuff{
    background-image:url(imgs/leaderboard/percentages.png);
    background-size:100 100;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:1024px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    background-position:center bottom;
}
```

Comment: Will you provide your HTML also?

Comment: It's not clear what's the problem. Do you really need `background-attachment:fixed;`?

Comment: As long as the browser window is at least 1024px wide, I want the background image to always be centered and at the bottom of the page. once the size of the window goes below 1024, it will not be centered anymore but aligned to the left side of the page, still positioned to the bottom of the page.

Comment: I adjusted the css with a media query. got it!

Answer (score 0):

use media queries. If you are only trying to change the position of the image, then the following will work

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .scroll-stuff {
        background-position:left bottom;
    }
}
```